# Efficiently Subtract Vector from Matrix (Scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I've got a large matrix stored as a scipy.sparse.csc_matrix and want to subtract a column vector from each one of the columns in the large matrix. This is a pretty common task when you're doing things like normalization/standardization, but I can't seem to find the proper way to do this efficiently.

Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
# mat is a 3x3 matrix
mat = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([[1, 2, 3],
                               [2, 3, 4],
                               [3, 4, 5]])

#vec is a 3x1 matrix (or a column vector)
vec = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([1,2,3]).T

""" 
I want to subtract `vec` from each of the columns in `mat` yielding...
    [[0, 1, 2],
     [0, 1, 2],
     [0, 1, 2]]
"""
```

One way to accomplish what I want is to hstack `vec` to itself 3 times, yielding a 3x3 matrix where each column is `vec` and then subtract that from `mat`. But again, I'm looking for a way to do this efficiently, and the hstacked matrix takes a long time to create. I'm sure there's some magical way to do this with slicing and broadcasting, but it eludes me.

Thanks!

EDIT: Removed the 'in-place' constraint, because sparsity structure would be constantly changing in an in-place assignment scenario.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't show it, because both the matrix and the vector you have chosen are dense. But if you did that operation on a truly sparse matrix, you would likely change the sparsity structure of the matrix (i.e. there would be non-zero values in places where before there was a zero value), which means that the operation can't really be done in-place.

Comment: yeah I realized the in-place constraint didn't make sense, so I edited the question to reflect that. I'll annotate that edit now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a start what would we do with dense arrays?

```
mat-vec.A # taking advantage of broadcasting
mat-vec.A[:,[0]*3] # explicit broadcasting
mat-vec[:,[0,0,0]] # that also works with csr matrix
```

In https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32664/numpy-scipy-optimization/33566
we found that using `as_strided` on the `mat.indptr` vector is the most efficient way of stepping through the rows of a sparse matrix.  (The `x.rows`, `x.cols` of an `lil_matrix` are nearly as good.  `getrow` is slow).  This function implements such as iteration.

```
def sum(X,v):
    rows, cols = X.shape
    row_start_stop = as_strided(X.indptr, shape=(rows, 2),
                            strides=2*X.indptr.strides)
    for row, (start, stop) in enumerate(row_start_stop):
        data = X.data[start:stop]
        data -= v[row]

sum(mat, vec.A)
print mat.A
```

I'm using `vec.A` for simplicity.  If we keep `vec` sparse we'd have to add a test for nonzero value at `row`.  Also this type of iteration only modifies the nonzero elements of `mat`.  `0's` are unchanged.

I suspect the time advantages will depend a lot on the sparsity of matrix and vector.  If `vec` has lots of zeros, then it makes sense to iterate, modifying only those rows of `mat` where `vec` is nonzero.  But `vec` is nearly dense like this example, it may be hard to beat `mat-vec.A`.

Comment: +1 Wah, this is even simpler than my answer! Can you refer to a documentation that refers to the usage of `A`? I can't seem to see that in the documentation

Comment: `mat.A` is just short hand for `mat.toarray()`.  It's modeled on dense uses like `.T`.

Comment: I see. I guess this should give the best performance? At least it's better than mine since mine is doing exactly the same thing, but it requires CSR, and I explicitly modify the `mat.data`

Comment: Ouch: `mat = np.asmatrix( np.ones( 10 ));  print hasattr( mat, "A" ), hasattr( mat, "toarray" )`

Comment: A dense matrix does not have a `.toarray` method, but a sparse one does.  Sparse also has a `.todense` method.  Dense also has a `.A1` attribute.

Comment: Yes, maddeningly inconsistent. Would you know of a wrapper lib for uniform ndarray / np matrix / scipy sparse, along he lines of BLAS ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary

So in short, if you use CSR instead of CSC, it's a one-liner:

```
mat.data -= numpy.repeat(vec.toarray()[0], numpy.diff(mat.indptr))
```

#### Explanation

If you realized it, this is better done in row-wise fashion, since we will deduct the same number from each row. In your example then: deduct 1 from the first row, 2 from the second row, 3 from the third row.

I actually encountered this in a real life application where I want to classify documents, each represented as a row in the matrix, while the columns represent words. Each document has a score which should be multiplied to the score of each word in that document. Using row representation of the sparse matrix, I did something similar to this (I modified my code to answer your question):

```
mat = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([[1, 2, 3],
                               [2, 3, 4],
                               [3, 4, 5]])

#vec is a 3x1 matrix (or a column vector)
vec = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([1,2,3]).T

# Use the row version
mat_row = mat.tocsr()
vec_row = vec.T

# mat_row.data contains the values in a 1d array, one-by-one from top left to bottom right in row-wise traversal.
# mat_row.indptr (an n+1 element array) contains the pointer to each first row in the data, and also to the end of the mat_row.data array
# By taking the difference, we basically repeat each element in the row vector to match the number of non-zero elements in each row
mat_row.data -= numpy.repeat(vec_row.toarray()[0],numpy.diff(mat_row.indptr))
print mat_row.todense()
```

Which results in:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

The visualization is something like this:

```
>>> mat_row.data
[1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5]
>>> mat_row.indptr
[0 3 6 9]
>>> numpy.diff(mat_row.indptr)
[3 3 3]
>>> numpy.repeat(vec_row.toarray()[0],numpy.diff(mat_row.indptr))
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
>>> mat_row.data -= numpy.repeat(vec_row.toarray()[0],numpy.diff(mat_row.indptr))
[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
>>> mat_row.todense()
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce fake dimensions by altering the `strides` of your vector. You can, with out additional allocation, "convert" your vector to a 3 x 3 matrix using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`. This [page](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/) has an example and a bit of a discussion about it along with some discussion of related topics (like views). Search the page for "Example: fake dimensions with strides."

There are also quite a few example on SO about this... but my searching skills are failing me now.

Comment: Ah... I did not know that. Though thinking about this that does make sense.

Comment: Couldn't Murad write an ndarray subclass that wraps the sparse matrix but by overriding `__getitem__` would allow the inbuilt ndarray striding code to be used before accessing the sparse array?

Comment: @BenWhale The built-in ndarray routines don't use the `__getitem__` method for anything relevant, but access the data directly with C code. So no, I don-t think that would work either...

Comment: Ops... I mean `__getslice__` or what ever is appropriate.