# Euclidean Distance between Scipy Sparse Matrix and Sparse Vector

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, knn, euclidean-distance

I am working on a KNN algorithm for a university assignment and at the moment I'm working on finding the Euclidean distance between each of the training vectors stored as a Scipy lil_matrix (due to the sparseness of the values in the vectors), and a testing vector stored as a 1 x n lil_matrix for the same reasons above.

To work out the euclidean distance I'm then doing the following code:

```
for positiveIndex, positivesComparison in enumerate(positives):
    result.append((spatial.distance.euclidean(positivesComparison.todense(),sentenceVector.todense() ), positiveIndex, 1))
```

Where sentenceVector is a lil_matrix of 1 row, and positives is a lil_matrix of size n x m.

I want to try and work out something faster than going through the positives matrix row by row and evaluating the euclidean distance every time, and maybe run the euclidean distance between the positives matrix and the sentenceVector vector, and return a 1 x m matrix with the euclidean distances.
The reason I want to do this is that the current system is relatively slow to compute as it is basically an NM time complexity as I need to compute more than one sentence test.
Is this possible, and if yes, how would I do it?

Note, the task is to evaluate performance using different K values for the KNN algorithm and not on the actual implementation of the KNN (although we are not allowed to use KNN libraries to do the task)

Answer (score 4):

You can compute batch Euclidean distances pretty easily:

```
In [10]: a = np.random.random(size=(4,5))

In [11]: b = np.random.random(size=(1,5))

In [12]: from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

In [13]: [euclidean(aa, b) for aa in a]
Out[13]: [1.1430615949614429, 0.568517046878056, 1.3302284168375587, 1.0581730230363529]

In [14]: np.sqrt(np.sum((a - b)**2, axis=1))
Out[14]: array([ 1.1431,  0.5685,  1.3302,  1.0582])
```

But we want to use sparse matrices, which makes things a little more difficult:

```
In [22]: import scipy.sparse as ss

In [23]: sa = ss.lil_matrix(a)

In [24]: sb = ss.lil_matrix(b)

In [25]: np.sqrt(np.sum((sa - sb)**2, axis=1))  # <-- ValueError: inconsistent shapes
```

It's possible to do, but you'll need to use [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20060753/10601).

More importantly, you should look at how big (and how sparse) your vectors really are. You might be faster leaving everything dense, and it will certainly save you some headache.

Finally, I'd avoid using LIL-format matrices, as they're one of the slowest formats available. For your case, look into CSR format.

**EDIT**: I forgot the simplest solution: use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html)!

```
In [36]: from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

In [37]: pairwise_distances(a, b)
Out[37]:
array([[ 1.1431],
       [ 0.5685],
       [ 1.3302],
       [ 1.0582]])

In [38]: pairwise_distances(sa, sb)
Out[38]:
array([[ 1.1431],
       [ 0.5685],
       [ 1.3302],
       [ 1.0582]])
```

Comment: I did initially just use a numpy array but the vector size is very large, and the data is very sparse. Having zero values stored resulted in the training set to be around 5gb large, with storing only non-zero values it went down to 20-30mb. Huge difference. I am using lil_matrix since I define the size of the matrix in the beginning, but then need to assign values to it by x,y coordinates, and only found ways to do it using a lil_matrix. I am not sure if I can use scikit-learn, will enquire about it, so for now I'll check out the some tricks article mentioned

Comment: If you can't use sklearn, you could always just adapt the relevant functions from it: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L109