# Elementwise addition of sparse scipy matrix vector with broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to best perform elementwise addition (and subtraction) of a sparse matrix and a sparse vector. I found [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060753/efficiently-subtract-vector-from-matrix-scipy) on SO:

```
mat = sp.csc_matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
vec = sp.csr_matrix([[1,2,1]])
mat.data += np.repeat(vec.toarray()[0], np.diff(mat.indptr))
```

But unfortunately it only updates non-zero values:

```
print(mat.todense())
[[2 0 0]
 [0 3 0]
 [0 0 2]]
```

The actual accepted answer on the SO thread:

```
def sum(X,v):
    rows, cols = X.shape
    row_start_stop = as_strided(X.indptr, shape=(rows, 2),
                            strides=2*X.indptr.strides)
    for row, (start, stop) in enumerate(row_start_stop):
        data = X.data[start:stop]
        data -= v[row]

sum(mat,vec.A[0])
```

Does the same thing. I'm unfortunately out of ideas by now, so I was hoping you could help me figuring out the best way to solve this.

EDIT:
I'm expecting it to do the same as a dense version of this would do:

```
np.eye(3) + np.asarray([[1,2,1]])
array([[ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Thanks

Comment: What is that addition supposed to produce?  Are you adding the `vec` values to just the nonzero values of `mat`, or to all values?  Will the result still be sparse?

Comment: I'd suggest a more general example, one that does not involve just 0s and 1s.

Comment: What's wrong with `mat+vec.A`?  Or `sparse.csr_matrix(mat+vec.A)` if the result must be in sparse format?  Look at the code for `mat.__add__`.

Comment: @hpaulj That would mean the necessity of creating a dense version of the matrix before converting it to sparse again. My matrices are simply too large for dense matrices to be an option.

Comment: Is the result going to be sparse or dense - in the sense of having lots of 0s or not?  Your example is not sparse.

Comment: @hpaulj The result is most definitely going to be sparse. I'm mainly adding to a few indices of a matrix with shape (100k, 100k)

Comment: Can you gives us an 10x10 example, that is definitely sparse?  I'm having problems visualizing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some tests with 10x10 sparse mat and vec:

```
In [375]: mat=sparse.rand(10,10,.1) 
In [376]: mat
Out[376]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [377]: mat.A
Out[377]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.15568621,  0.59916335,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       ...
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.15552687,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.47483064,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])

In [378]: vec=sparse.coo_matrix([0,1,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0]).tocsr()
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

maxymoo's solution:

```
def addvec(mat,vec):
    Mc = mat.tocsc()
    for i in vec.nonzero()[1]:
        Mc[:,i]=sparse.csc_matrix(Mc[:,i].todense()+vec[0,i])
    return Mc
```

And variation that uses `lil` format, which is supposed to be more efficient when changing the sparsity structure:

```
def addvec2(mat,vec):
    Ml=mat.tolil()
    vec=vec.tocoo()                                            
    for i,v in zip(vec.col, vec.data):
        Ml[:,i]=sparse.coo_matrix(Ml[:,i].A+v)
    return Ml
```

The sumation has 38 nonzero terms, up from 10 in the original `mat`.  It adds the 3 columns from `vec`.  That's a big change in sparsity.

```
In [382]: addvec(mat,vec)
Out[382]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 38 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [383]: _.A
Out[383]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ,  0.        ,
         0.15568621,  0.59916335,  3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       ...
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.15552687,  2.        ,  0.        ,
         0.47483064,  0.        ,  3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Same output with addvec2:

```
In [384]: addvec2(mat,vec)
Out[384]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 38 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

And in timing, `addvec2` does better than 2x

```
In [385]: timeit addvec(mat,vec)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.51 ms per loop

In [386]: timeit addvec2(mat,vec)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop
```

and the dense equivalents:

```
In [388]: sparse.coo_matrix(mat+vec.A)
Out[388]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 38 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [389]: timeit sparse.coo_matrix(mat+vec.A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 716 µs per loop

In [390]: timeit sparse.coo_matrix(mat.A+vec.A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 338 µs per loop
```

A version that might save on temporary dense matrix space, runs in the same time:

```
In [393]: timeit temp=mat.A; temp+=vec.A; sparse.coo_matrix(temp)
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop
```

So the dense version does 5-7x better than my sparse version.

For a really large `mat`, memory issues might chew into the dense performance, but the iterative sparse solution(s) isn't going to shine either.

I may be able to squeeze more performance from `addvec2` by indexing `Ml` more efficiently.  `Ml.data[3],Ml.rows[3]` is considerably faster than `Ml[3,:]` or `Ml[:,3]`.

```
def addvec3(mat,vec):
    Mtl=mat.T.tolil()
    vec=vec.tocoo()
    n = mat.shape[0]
    for i,v in zip(vec.col, vec.data):
        t = np.zeros((n,))+v
        t[Mtl.rows[i]] += Mtl.data[i]
        t = sparse.coo_matrix(t)
        Mtl.rows[i] = t.col
        Mtl.data[i] = t.data
    return Mtl.T

In [468]: timeit addvec3(mat,vec)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop
```

A modest improvement, but not as much as I'd hoped. And squeezing a bit more:

```
def addvec3(mat,vec):
    Mtl = mat.T.tolil()
    vec = vec.tocoo(); 
    t0 = np.zeros((mat.shape[0],))
    r0 = np.arange(mat.shape[0])
    for i,v in zip(vec.col, vec.data):
        t = t0+v
        t[Mtl.rows[i]] += Mtl.data[i]
        Mtl.rows[i] = r0
        Mtl.data[i] = t
    return Mtl.T

In [531]: timeit mm=addvec3(mat,vec)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hmm interesting... for  `mat=sp.rand(10**3,10**3,.001)` the sparse version is 5x faster ... not amazing though.

Comment: The sparcity of `vec` makes a big difference in relative timings.  It doesn't affect the time for the dense version, but the others iterate over the nonzero values.

Answer (score 0):

So your original matrix is sparse, the vector is sparse but in the resulting matrix the columns corresponding to nonzero coordinates in your vector will be dense.

So we may as well materialise those columns as dense matrices

```
def addvec(mat,vec):
   for i in vec.nonzero()[1]:
      mat[:,i] = sp.csc_matrix(mat[:,i].todense() + vec[0,i])
   return mat
```

Comment: I have to use `for i in vec.nonzero()[1]:`.  I also get an efficiency warning, due to the `mat[:,i]` assignment.

Comment: You're right, i've made that that change in my answer. I don't get the efficiency warning though. What verson of scipy are you using? I'm using 0.14 on Python 3.4

Comment: Same version; I get this warning the first time (in a session) that I do something to change the sparsity of a csc or csr matrix. `Changing the sparsity structure of a csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.`